# Can C++ compiler automatically optimize float to double for me?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, double

I was wondering that maybe double is faster on some machines than float.

However, the operations I am performing really only require the precision of floats. However, they are in image processing and I would desire using the **fastest possible** one.

Can I use float everywhere and trust that the optimizing VC++ 2008 compiler will convert it to double if it deems it is more appropriate? I don't see how this would break code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No.  Precision is a design decision made by the designer.  "deems it is more appropriate"?  How would that work?  Can you give a rule for this?  A rule that wouldn't ruin someone's calculations?

Comment: A 32-bit `float` is at least as fast a [64/128-bit] `double` on 32-bit machines.

Comment: No it will not optimize it for you.However, you can always make it a register

Comment: @S.Lott
_Can you give a rule for this? A rule that wouldn't ruin someone's calculations?_

I was thinking that all 'float's in the code could be replaced with 'double's without any big impact on calculations. Floating-point optimizations are known to "break" non-robust calculations already anyways.

Comment: If you want it to be `double`, declare it so. When compilers optimize, they are doing you a favor - they don't *have* to do it.

Comment: @Amil: I've been in a situation where substituting `double` for `float` *did* have an impact on calculations. I was working on an algorithm in C++, which used `float`, and my implementation was being verified in Matlab, which used `double`, by a scientist. (This was 10 years ago, before Matlab had good support for things other than `double` or `unsigned char`.) As a result of this mismatch, we couldn't compare the outputs for equality. Instead, we had to guess an "error threshold", and compare the distance between the results to this value. It was extra work and didn't always work.

Answer (score 3):

No, the compiler will not change a fundamental type like float to a double for optimization.

If you think this is likely, use a typedef for your floating point in a common header, e.g. `typedef float FASTFLOAT;` and use FASTFLOAT (or whatever you name it) throughout your code.  You can then change one central typedef, and change the type throughout your code.

My own experience is that float and double are basically comparable in performance on x86/x64 platforms now for math operations, and I tend to prefer double.  If you are processing a lot of data (and hitting memory bandwidth issues, instead of computationally bound), you may get some performance benefit from the fact that floats are half the size of doubles.

You will also want to explore the effects of the various optimization flags.  Depending on your target platform requirements, you may be able to optimize more aggresively.

Comment: It may not change the type of the variable. But it could still choose to do arithmetic on doubles if the extra speed was useful and convert back to float for storage in the variable.

Comment: True enough.  Also, as I recall, float operations are performed on 40-bit values in hardware, which are then truncated to 32-bit for storage.  (Can anyone find a reference to that?)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the compiler doesn't change float types unless it has to, and never in storage declarations.

`float` will be no slower than `double`, but if you really want fast processing, you need to look into either using a compiler that can generate SSE2 or SSE3 code or you need to write your heavy-processing routines using those instructions. IIRC, there are tools that can help you micromanage the processor's pipeline if necessary. Last I messed with this (years ago), Intel had a library called IPP that could help as well by vectorizing your math.

I have never heard of an architecture where `float` was slower than `double`, if only for the fact that memory bandwidth requirements double if you use `double`. Any FPU that can do a single-cycle `double` operation can do a single-cycle `float` operation with a little modification at most.

Mark's got a good idea, though: profile your code if you think it's slow. You might find the real problem is somewhere else, like hidden typecasts or function-call overhead from something you thought was inlined not getting inlined.

Comment: Although not exactly a float vs double issue, on the x86 the FPU's registers are 80 bits wide, while floats and doubles are 32 and 64 bits, respectively. A strict reading of the C standard requires frequent truncations to the width of the storage type you requested; this takes time. GCC has a `-ffast-math` flag to disable these truncations, and perform some intermediate computations at higher-than-allowed precision; I don't know about MSVC, however.

Answer (score 0):

When the code needs to store the variable in memory chances are on most architectures it will take 32 bits for a `float` and 64 bits for a `double`. Doing the memory size conversion would prevent complete optimization of such.

Are you sure that the floating point math is the bottleneck in your application? Perhaps profiling would reveal another possible source of improvement.